# Connection to SQL Server database using sql_exporter and Prometheus but can't execute custom metrics on db

Tags: sql-server, prometheus, grafana, sql-server-express, prometheus-alertmanager

So, I've went through many of the options to get this set up and none worked with my SQL Server setup except using `sql_exporter`. There is a successful connection where I can read all the built-in metrics but when I tried my own query on a specific database and its table there is always something wrong with my query such as "Invalid Object" when trying to reach the database. There have been many resources I have attempted to use but would mostly like a custom metric like: https://sysdig.com/blog/monitor-sql-server-prometheus/.

**sql_exporter.yml:**

```
# The target to monitor and the collectors to execute on it.
target:
  # Data source name always has a URI schema that matches the driver name. In some cases (e.g. MySQL)
  # the schema gets dropped or replaced to match the driver expected DSN format.
  data_source_name: 'sqlserver://username:password@localhost:1433'

  # Collectors (referenced by name) to execute on the target.
  collectors: [mssql_standard]

# Collector files specifies a list of globs. One collector definition is read from each matching file.
collector_files: 
  - "*.collector.yml"
```

**prometheus.yml:**

```
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: "prometheus"

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]

  - job_name: 'sql_server'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9966']
```

When I tried the custom metric in the post I linked, `sql_exporter` crashes instantly no errors. My database is being found in the standard metrics of https://github.com/free/sql_exporter but I am unsure the syntax to execute a simple `SELECT db_value FROM db_table`. I understand there are ways out there and I've tried so will need assistance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where are you specifying the database name? You either need to set the SQL Login's default database to the correct location or you need to include it in your query (if such a tool as sql_exporter allows it), e.g.: `use your_database_name; select column_name from schema_name.table_name`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Okay I am able to make the query thanks to the `use database_name;` . Now am stuck with the issue of not having correct `key_label` and `values` for my metric. Not much out there on how to correctly do this I get the error from sql_exporter "was collected before with the same name and label values"

Comment: You should probably ask a new question about your new error, but do take a look at [Prometheus Collector fails with "collected metric was collected before with the same name and label values"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900346/prometheus-collector-fails-with-collected-metric-was-collected-before-with-the) first to see if it sheds any light on the matter.